# install_github or install_bitbucket crashing R with segfault error

Tags: r, github, devtools, install.packages

I'm using R on the university HPC cluster and now they have upgraded to R/3.3.0 I'm looking to install my code and supporting packages to match my local setup.  However I'm having problems with the commands `install_github` and `install_bitbucket` to install my code (and another package I use).

These are the commands and errors from the R session:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("config-i1/smooth")
Downloading GitHub repo config-i1/smooth@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/config-i1/smooth/zipball/master
Installing smooth

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x4000000079, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call(digest_impl, object, as.integer(algoint), as.integer(length),     as.integer(skip), as.integer(raw), as.integer(seed))
 2: `_digest`(c(list(repos, type), lapply(`_additional`, function(x) eval(x[[2L]],     environment(x)))), algo = "sha512")
 3: available_packages(repos, type)
 4: package_deps(deps, repos = repos, type = type)
 5: dev_package_deps(pkg, repos = repos, dependencies = dependencies,     type = type, force_deps = force_deps, quiet = quiet)
 6: install_deps(pkg, dependencies = dependencies, upgrade = upgrade_dependencies,     threads = threads, force_deps = force_deps, quiet = quiet,     ...)
 7: install(source, ..., quiet = quiet, metadata = metadata)
 8: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 9: vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
10: install_remotes(remotes, quiet = quiet, ...)
11: install_github("config-i1/smooth")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

I receive a similar error with: `install_bitbucket("wellermatt/forecastR"`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux release 6.7 (Carbon)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C                    LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.iso88591        LC_COLLATE=C
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.iso88591    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.iso88591
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.iso88591       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C                  LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.iso88591 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.11.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] withr_1.0.1   memoise_1.0.0 digest_0.6.9
```

I have tried to upgrade `RCurl` and `devtools`, but neither has helped.  WOuld anybody be able to suggest a potential solution - I'm not able to find one on the web at the moment.  I guess I can try to download the whole repository from github and then install from source that way but this doesn't help my workflow which currently pulls the latest version automatically.

---- EDIT -----

The cluster manager at Lancaster has tried the install also and has looked into the traceback.  He reports as follows:

Let me know how that goes. I can replicate the crash myself (which may in itself be odd, as I expected your codebase to require authentication), but I’m none the wiser. Here’s the last few lines of strace (which logs systems calls only) leading up to the segfault:

```
read(3, "Package: forecastR\nType: Package"..., 16384) = 492
read(3, "", 12288)                      = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 492
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f276cdfe000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/tmp/RtmpjNlvQb/devtools2d0a1128ed80/wellermatt-forecastr-d5b58631b3a1/src", 0x7fff1a81bdb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Installing forecastR\n", 21)  = 21
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
```

The failed stat() call may or may not be an issue – were you expecting your package to have src dir? If not, this may simply be an expected test.

Comment: have you tried to install it with `CC=clang` and `CXX=clang++` in your Makevars?
See this post: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/322

Comment: I've never used Makevars before, will look into it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2013-February/009949.html

Comment: @Hack-R I'm connecting via ssh without the -X option so I don't see how the `tcltk` bit helps.  I'm able to `library(tcltk)` but this doesn't have an impact on my problem.
@J_F I've tried this by creating a file at `~/.R/Makevars`, didn't fix it.  Slightly baffled!